# Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSqlPlatform may not support it

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine

> Developing using Symfony 2.7

I have ***entity*** which contain attribute

```
/**
 * @var array
 * @ORM\Column(name="new_entry_name", type="json_array", nullable=true)
 */
protected $newEntryName;
```

but when i update my ***schema*** using

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

it shows me ***error***

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                         

Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSqlPlatform may not support it.
```

In ***config.yml*** file i have added this type.

`doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "pdo_pgsql"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        mapping_types:
            enum: string
            set: string
            varbinary: string
            tinyblob: text
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType`

what should i do to avoid this error .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error add

```
json: json_array
```

or

```
json: json
```

in `config.yml` under `mapping_types` section.

So, `mapping_types` section should look like this:

```
mapping_types:
    enum: string
    set: string
    varbinary: string
    tinyblob: text
    json: json_array
```

Comment: Its already there .

mapping_types:
            enum: string
            set: string
            varbinary: string
            tinyblob: text
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType